# Spark get datatype of nested object

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have some JSON data which looks like this:

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":[
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "key3":{
        "key31":"value31",
        "key32":"value32"
    },
    "key4":[
        {
            "key41":"value411",
            "key42":"value412",
            "key43":"value413"
        },
        {
            "key41":"value421",
            "key42":"value422",
            "key43":"value423"
        }
    ],
    "key5":{
        "key51":[
            {
                "key511":"value511",
                "key512":"value512",
                "key513":"value513"
            },
            {
                "key511":"value521",
                "key512":"value522",
                "key513":"value523"
            }
        ]
    },
    "key6":{
        "key61":{
            "key611":[
                {
                    "key_611":"value_611",
                    "key_612":"value_612",
                    "key_613":"value_613"
                },
                {
                    "key_611":"value_621",
                    "key_612":"value_622",
                    "key_613":"value_623"
                },
                {
                    "key_611":"value_621",
                    "key_612":"value_622",
                    "key_613":"value_623"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It contains the a mix of simple, complex and array type values.

If I try to get the datatype of key1 `schema.("key1").dataType`, I get `StringType` and likewise for key2, key3 and key4.

For key5 also, I get `StructType`.

But when I try to get the datatype for key51, which is nested under key5 using `schema.("key5.key51").dataType`, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "key5.key51" does not exist.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:263)
  ... 48 elided
```

The main intention for me is to be able to explode a given type if its of `ArrayType` and not explode for any other type.

The explode function is able to recognize this given key (key5.key51) properly and exploding the array. But the problem is with determining the datatype.

One possible solution for me is to do a select of key5.key51 as a separate column key51 and then explode that column.

But is there any better and more elegant way of doing this while still being able to determine the datatype of the given column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to `select` the field of interest, and then retrieve the schema:

```
df.select("key5.key51").schema.head.dataType
```

Using full schema directly, would require traversing schema, and might be hard to do right, while with embedded `.`, `StructTypes` and complex types (`Maps` and `Arrays`).

Comment: This will return an array type if the field is within a nested array regardless of the actual field type.  This is because the json parsing tries to return all values at that path (albeit not successfully when the structure gets complex enough)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some (recursive) code to find all `ArrayType` fields names:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def findArrayTypes(parents:Seq[String],f:StructField) : Seq[String] = {
  f.dataType match {
    case array: ArrayType => parents
    case struct: StructType => struct.fields.toSeq.map(f => findArrayTypes(parents:+f.name,f)).flatten
    case _ => Seq.empty[String]
  }
}


val arrayTypeColumns = df.schema.fields.toSeq
  .map(f => findArrayTypes(Seq(f.name),f))
  .filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString("."))
```

For your dataframe, this gives:

```
arrayTypeColumns.foreach(println)


key2
key4
key5.key51
key6.key61.key611
```

This does not work yet for arrays inside maps or nested arrays