# Get data type from a StructType column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I’m reading an Avro file from S3. I’m trying to write it as a delta file. I have the following schema

```
|--test: struct
   |--test2: struct
      |--test3: struct
```

When I run:

```
print(df.schema['test'].dataType)
```

I got the correct output, but when I run

```
print(df.schema['test.test2'].dataType)
```

I got the following error:

```
'No StructField named test.test2'
```

I need to get the struct schema because sometimes spark infers that some struct columns are string since they are empty. What I’m trying to do is verify if the column type is a StringType or a StructureType. However, like I said before, I can’t get the data type of a nested structure.

My doubt is: Is it possible to get the datatype of a nested column structure without iterating over it? If not, what is the best approach to iterate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark get datatype of nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265845/spark-get-datatype-of-nested-object)

Comment: When I run the code `df.select('test.test2').schema.head.dataType` I got the error `'StructType' object has no attribute head`

Comment: Ok, so you expect to get `struct` as output, or `StructType` object ?

Comment: Anyone of them is ok. The only thing I need is to access the type of the nested strucutre. Imagine that a `test4` string type exists within `test3`. I just need to access this data type. I used 3 strucutres as example…

Comment: "to access the type of the nested strucutre" - Note, the type of the nested strucutre would be `StructType`. Otherwise you want to get a type of `StructField` ?

Comment: Yes. It would be StructType!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I’ve edited my question to add more context to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a nested `StructType` as object, use `schema` attribute on *selection* of the target column.

Sample (assuming having some `data`):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StructType([
        StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
        StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
        StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
    ])),
    StructField('state', StringType(), True),
    StructField('gender', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
# df.printSchema()
print(df.select('name.firstname').schema)
```

---

```
StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType(), True)])
```

---

To get the inner data type of a concrete `StructField` use the following accessing scheme:

```
print(df.select('name.firstname').schema['firstname'].dataType)
```

---

```
StringType()
```